# How can I translate text containing HTML using IBM Bluemix language translation service?

Tags: php, html, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, language-translation

For example, I have the content:

```
<p><strong>Je vais être</strong> va demain.</p>
```

If I pass this content to https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/language-translation/api/v2/translate as plain text, eg:

```
Je vais être va demain.
```

Then I'll get back exactly what I want:

```
I'll be going tomorrow.
```

However, I still need the content in HTML, not plain text.  If I pass in the text with url encoding or with entities escaped, the returned text is severely affected.

With URL encoding:

```
<p><strong>Je   will   être</strong>   will   demain. </p>
```

With html entities escaped:

```
<p><strong>I'll be</strong> will tomorrow.</p>
```

I've also noted that placing any sort of delimiter in the content affects the translation.  For example, using a carat:

```
Je vais être^ va demain.
```

Will return the translation:

```
I'll be ^ will tomorrow.
```

So the solution would have to have no delimiters in the requested translation.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Language Translation API (https://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/language-translation/api/v2/#translate), I see that you can put a list of multiple text inputs in the request.  I would just strip the HTML flags in order, and request translation on the smaller chunks of text.  You could do this with a simple stack - pushing either HTML tags onto the stack, or text to be translated.  Then pop all of it off of the stack once you get the translation responses back.

Comment: Translation may be not correct if small chunks of text are translated out of context.

Comment: Very true.  Unfortunately when doing the translation, the <strong> tag may not map neatly into the translated response.  I don't know of any way around this.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the HTML to [AlchemyLanguage Text Extraction](https://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/alchemy-language/api/v1/#text_raw) and extract the text that later you send to LanguageTranslation.

In `curl` you will do:

```
curl -X POST \
-d "apikey=$API_KEY" \
-d "outputMode=json" \
--data-urlencode html@tech_crunch.html \
-d "url=http://techcrunch.com/2016/01/29/ibm-watson-weather-company-sale/" \
"https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/calls/html/HTMLGetRawText"
```

and the output is:

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "usage": "By accessing AlchemyAPI or using information generated by AlchemyAPI, you are agreeing to be bound by the AlchemyAPI Terms of Use: http://www.alchemyapi.com/company/terms.html",
  "url": "http://techcrunch.com/2016/01/29/ibm-watson-weather-company-sale/",
  "text": "IBM Closes Weather Co. Purchase, Names David Kenny New Head Of Watson Platform  |  TechCrunch"
}
```